# Argument attribute definition for Qore function implemented via QPP

Tags: qore

I'd like to define a CPP *__attribute__* for (Qore script) functions implemented in *.qpp* and preprocessed into plain *.cpp*. 
Qore script class methods may be called from C++ side. In this case an empty function is implemented in QPP class definition and preprocessed in .cpp file. C++ compiler will raise warning messages during compilation. Solution is GNU attribute `unused`. Is somehow possible to define argument attributes in .qpp ?

```
MyClass::onAction(int arg0, reference arg1) {
}
```

Expanded in cpp as:

```
static QoreValue MyClass_onAction_HashBGD(QoreObject* self, MyClassObject *o, const QoreValueList* args, q_rt_flags_t rtflags, ExceptionSink* xsink)
```

Note: *ScopeGuard.h* contains `#define UNUSED_VARIABLE __attribute__((unused))` but qpp syntax does not support "normal" C++ usage as argument prefix.

As there are also automatically expanded arguments seems function flag is to be implemented.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is already implemented; look at the implementation for `[doc]` in `qpp.cpp`; if you declare a parameter variable in a qpp file as `[doc]`, it means that no C++ glue for that variable will be generated, and the parameter variable is for documentation only.

Example in `QC_StreamWriter.qpp`:

```
nothing StreamWriter::printf(string[doc] fmt, ...) {
   sw->f_printf(args, xsink);
}
```

This generates the following C++ code:

```
// nothing StreamWriter::printf(string fmt, ...){}
static QoreValue StreamWriter_printf_VsVV(QoreObject* self, StreamWriter* sw, const QoreValueList* args, q_rt_flags_t rtflags, ExceptionSink* xsink) {
# 146 "QC_StreamWriter.qpp"
   sw->printf(args, xsink);
   return QoreValue();
}
```

I hope this helps!